# How to run samples. Visual Studio 2010

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna, sample

This might be a dumb question but I've been developing for a while and I still can't figure this out. Sometimes when I download samples for WP7 applications it shades out the "run application". I can build it and it succeeds but I can't run it. Anyone know how I can run these samples?

The sample I'm looking at is the "Farseer Physics Engine 3.3.1 Samples XNA" at http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/releases/view/64108.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WP7` project hasn't been set as the default one. In the `Solution Explorer`, right-click on `Samples XNA WP7` and click `Set as Startup Project`. You should then be able to deploy.

Edit - If you find that you can't deploy because you get:

> The application could not be launched for debugging. Verify that the
>   application is installed on the target device.

go to `Properties`...`Configuration Settings` and make sure `Build` and `Deploy` are both checked

Comment: Interesting, this still didn't work for me. It would refuse to deploy, but then if I fired up the App Deployment tool I could deploy the xap to the emulator no problem. After this the sample would also load from VS. Very odd.

Comment: The emulator opens, then VS pops up and says `The application could not be launched for debugging. Verify that the application is installed on the target device.` Yet the same xap deploys fine through App Deploy tool.

Comment: Strange. Try going to `Properties`...`Configuration Settings` and make sure `Build and Deploy` are both checked.

Comment: Bingo, Deploy was not checked. Add that to your answer and this is the correct answer. Not my question though, just interested :)

Answer (score 1):

In the device dropdown is `Windows Phone Emulator` or `Windows Phone Device` selected?
Sometimes with samples that dropdown will have neither selected and therefore can not run until one is selected.

Comment: It's grayed out so I can't select anything. I added what sample I was looking at in my post. It looks like there are a lot of demo's to run but I don't know how to pick a specific one and run it.